# HTML/ASP.net/login flow Facebook: how to make redirect URL to my site invisible in address bar ie10

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, response.redirect

When the user clicks an asp button on my page a redirect to:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={app-id}&redirect_uri={redirect-uri}
```

will happen. Facebook will then redirect back to my own redirect-uri (with a code).  How can I avoid that the user can see this redirect-uri and code in the address bar of the Internet Explorer browser?  I think this must be possible because when I redirect to facebook and the user is already logged in then I don't see the url changing to //www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth, facebook redirects immediately back before the uri change gets visible in the address bar of ie. Don't have this issue with Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pass some URL parameters in your Facebook return URL, then you can simply do another redirect on your site's landing page to a URL without parameters after you've done the necessary checks.

Of course if you don't need any parameter then just set your FB return URL accordingly to a page without any parameter.

Comment: Even when I redirect immediately in the page_load of my landing page (for example to a 'welcome user page')  I can see the url in the address bar changing from my login page=>my landing page(with the FB code)=> my "welcome user page" . When I look on professional websites like for example Strava.com I don't see the 2nd step in the address bar, they go immediately from the login page to the 'welcome user' page, also in IE10. I can see they also have a redirect parameter (landing page) different from the login or 'welcome user' page.